# How to compare two characters without case sensitivity in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, compare

I am trying to compare two specific characters in two strings,but I want to make the comparing **without case sensitivity**. How can I do this?

right now I am using a code like that:

```
if (str1[i]==str2[j]) printf("Equal");
```

but I want to do this without case sensivity.

Thank you in advance for taking your time to help!

Comment: What are the language, character encoding / code page and the type of the element of your strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use low case for both chars, for example by using tolower function:

```
if (tolower(str1[i])==tolower(str2[j])) printf("Equal");
```

Also keep in mind: tolower does not work for multibyte char. So for those chars you should use other function

Comment: will tolower() function effect the original char in string? either way thank you for your answer!

Comment: no, you pass char by value, not by pointer. so its impossible for this function to change it

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve your requirement by converting both of the character to either upper or lower case character using toupper() or tolower().

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> //For tolower()

int main()
{
    char str1[]="Time", str2[]="time";
    /*
     * Just for an example i am comparing the first char
     * from 2 different strings.
     */
    if(tolower(str1[0]) ==tolower(str2[0])) {
        printf("Char's are equal\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Char's are not equal");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> Char's are equal

Comment: You have two strings, but you only compare their first char. Shouldn't there be a loop?